# Java Reporting Component Retain Color Depth

Tags: java, crystal-reports

In Visual Studio .NET there is a Crystal report option to retain color depth. Is there an equivalent option in the Java Reporting Component? I am using PrintOutputController to export a PDF. It appears it is retaining color depth, and I would like not to. This will reduce the overall size of the PDF.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted SAP and they stated there is no equivalent option.

This is most relevant when the report contains several images. Consider loading and rescaling the images into POJOs. This can reduce size significantly. Further compression can be used if still not to an acceptable level.